# jQuery verification of select list contents

Tags: jquery

Is it possible using jQuery to verify if the following HTML select list contains any items?

HTML Select List of Countries which will initially be empty and may remain so unless populated.

```
<select size="5" name="Country" multiple="multiple" id="Country"> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will return true when there are items in the select.

```
alert($("#Country").children().length > 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#Country').children().length > 0) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (0 == $('#Country option').length) {
    // no options
} else {
    // options!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Country option").length > 0
```